# cElementTree.interparse() doesn't accept custom parser

Tags: python, xml-parsing, celementtree

I parse XML file on Python with ElementTree. I found out that C implementation of cElementTree work very fast comparing to regular one. But I have also discovered construction:

```
xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse(filename, parser=MyCystomParser())
```

wont work. You will see something like:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parser'
```

Meanwhile same construction with 'xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse' does work.

I use custom parser to keep comments while parsing XML file (default parser ignores/removes it).

Does anyone know why in C implementation it doesn't work? The 'parser' argument was already in ElementTree when cElementTree released.

Comment: Why would you need a custom parser? The whole point of iterparse is that any customization is done by the code that calls it, not hidden away in the parser's state machine.

Comment: To save comments during parsing XML file

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) clearly states: `If not given, the standard XMLParser parser is used. parser is not supported by cElementTree`

Comment: Is your question "Why did Gregory Smith not add `parser` support to `cElementTree` at some point before everything got rewritten for Python 3.x?" If so, I don't think it's a very useful question for SO. If not, there's nothing to say beyond karthikr's answer (and the docs).

Comment: @karthikr Indeed. Now I need to find something similar by speed

Comment: @IliaShakitko: Three choices: (1) Upgrade to Python 3.3+. (2) Get the latest external `ElementTree` version off PyPI or effbot.org and use that instead of the stdlib version. (3) Use the `lxml` implementation of the same API instead of using ElementTree itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why in C implementation it doesn't work?

Well, yeah, because it's [*documented*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) to not work:

> *parser* is not supported by `cElementTree`.

But why didn't they make it work?

The version of ElementTree that was incorporated into Python 2.5 did not have a `parser` argument on `iterparse`. This feature was only added in Python 3.2. It was then backported to Python 2.7.* (Note that it's not there in [2.6](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse).)

Python 3.x does not have `cElementTree`—instead, it just has a single `ElementTree` implementation, with C accelerator code that it uses wherever possible. So, it would have been much more work to backport the new feature to `cElementTree` than to `ElementTree`. And presumably it wasn't important enough for anyone to bother doing.

Also, note that ElementTree is developed and maintained outside of Python's stdlib, by Frederik Lundh, [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm). I believe Gregory P. Smith drives the integration-into-the-stdlib work, but I could be wrong. So, you could ask either of them, or ask on the python-dev list, if you want any more details. But I'm pretty sure the answer will just be "it wasn't important enough to bother doing".

---

* Technically, it was added in ElementTree 1.3, the version incorporated into Python 3.2 and 2.7. See the What's New docs for [2.7](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/2.7.html#updated-module-elementtree-1-3) and [3.2](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.2.html#elementtree).